# Flutter: How to load JSON into a PageView

Tags: flutter

I'm hoping someone can tell me how to load JSON in to a PageView. Each page in the PageView will contain a ListView which will use Card widgets to display each Job from the JSON.

The JOB_DATE will dictate which page the job is displayed on. So in the JSON below, the first 3 items are on one date and the next 2 items are on the following date. So page 1 should display the first 3 items and page 2 should display items 4 & 5.

JSON :

```
{
   "rows":[
      { "JOBID":23, "JOB_DATE":1588809600000, "START_TIME":"07:30", "JOB_NAME":"Cleaner" },
      { "JOBID":24, "JOB_DATE":1588809600000, "START_TIME":"08:30", "JOB_NAME":"Manager" }
      { "JOBID":25, "JOB_DATE":1588809600000, "START_TIME":"12:30", "JOB_NAME":"Caretaker" }
      { "JOBID":26, "JOB_DATE":1588896000000, "START_TIME":"08:30", "JOB_NAME":"Manager" }
      { "JOBID":27, "JOB_DATE":1588896000000, "START_TIME":"13:30", "JOB_NAME":"Caretaker" }
   ]
}
```

How would I code this to split the JSON up to the different pages?

Thanks heaps for any help.

Cheers,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) Json to dart class converter to quickly get a dart class for you JSON data structure. Then I would use the resulting dart class to parse your Json into a list of jobs in dart and then use that list on a specific page's ListView data source by only selecting the values with the specific sTARTTIME value you want to display on that page.

```
class Job {
  List<Rows> rows;

  Job({this.rows});

  Job.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['rows'] != null) {
      rows = new List<Rows>();
      json['rows'].forEach((v) {
        rows.add(new Rows.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.rows != null) {
      data['rows'] = this.rows.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Rows {
  int jOBID;
  int jOBDATE;
  String sTARTTIME;
  String jOBNAME;

  Rows({this.jOBID, this.jOBDATE, this.sTARTTIME, this.jOBNAME});

  Rows.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    jOBID = json['JOBID'];
    jOBDATE = json['JOB_DATE'];
    sTARTTIME = json['START_TIME'];
    jOBNAME = json['JOB_NAME'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['JOBID'] = this.jOBID;
    data['JOB_DATE'] = this.jOBDATE;
    data['START_TIME'] = this.sTARTTIME;
    data['JOB_NAME'] = this.jOBNAME;
    return data;
  }
}
```

You can parse our JSON like this in your flutter app:

```
import 'dart:convert';    
...
Job jobs = Job.fromJson(json.decode(jsonString));
...
final firstPageData = jobs.rows.where((row) => row.jOBDATE == 1588809600000).toList();
final secondPageData = jobs.rows.where((row) => row.jOBDATE == 1588896000000).toList();
```

Comment: I use the Json to Dart converter for all my json classes. So I can get this far, but I'm not sure how to select only the values that match the JOB_DATE that I want for each page in the PageView. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: No problem. You can do something as simple as filtering the items in your list or group them like the other answer suggested. Please find edits in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can you groupBy function from 'package:collection/collection.dart'

```
var json = {
   "rows":[
      { "JOBID":23, "JOB_DATE":1588809600000, "START_TIME":"07:30", "JOB_NAME":"Cleaner" },
      { "JOBID":24, "JOB_DATE":1588809600000, "START_TIME":"08:30", "JOB_NAME":"Manager" }
      { "JOBID":25, "JOB_DATE":1588809600000, "START_TIME":"12:30", "JOB_NAME":"Caretaker" }
      { "JOBID":26, "JOB_DATE":1588896000000, "START_TIME":"08:30", "JOB_NAME":"Manager" }
      { "JOBID":27, "JOB_DATE":1588896000000, "START_TIME":"13:30", "JOB_NAME":"Caretaker" }
   ]
}

List<Map<String, dynamic> rows = json['rows']
Map<dynamic, List<Map<String, dynamic>> sortedRow = groupBy(rows, (row) => row['JOB_DATE']
```

And you will have a map where keys are (1588809600000, 1588896000000) and values are lists of your objects.

After that you can create PageView with a ListView of your objects